# Script to list httpd instances

Tags: httpd, ps

I have a RHEL7 server (no GUI) running several distinct instances of httpd (distinct PID files, not defined as services...don't ask).

Trying to build a simple script that will tell me which of my httpd instances are actually started. If I run **ps -ef | grep httpd**, I get a listing that looks pretty much like I want, but I get a hit for every PID, which ends up giving me several hundred results. I'd like something that would give me one line for each instance.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the existing PID files, if you have them:

```
ps -f $(cat pidfile1 pidfile2 pidfile3 ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! I'm doing `ps -f $(cat /run/httpd/*.pid)` and it works perfectly.